# driver.quit()/driver.close() is not working in windows 10 and winium 1.6.0

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, windows-10

I have a maven project for testing windows desktop application(Calculator) using winium in windows 10 system(java). But after all testcase finished running the driver is not getting quit ie, application still be there not getting closed. I have researched a lot about this but didn't find any solution. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Are you running the app by "lnk" or specify the exe file to launch?

Comment: Using .exe extension

Comment: @SarithaKS have you got any solution?